# Saving Objects to File without duplication

Tags: java, file, awt, actionlistener

I have a problem in saving objects to a text file.

Here is the piece of code i have

```
if(action.equals("Save Person List"))
    {
        f1 = new File("PersonList.txt");
        if(f1.exists())
        {
            f1.delete();
            f1 = new File("PersonList.txt");
        }

        try {
            fWriter = new FileWriter(f1, true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        pWriter = new PrintWriter(fWriter, true);

        for(Person p: pList)
        {
            pWriter.println(p.getFName());
            pWriter.println(p.getLName());
            pWriter.println(p.getPNo());
            pWriter.println(p.getSalary());
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Person List Stored in File 'PersonList.txt'");
    }
```

In the code above, upon the click of the button, the program is able to save an arraylist of objects to a file (which i am happy about), but supposing i add more objects to the arraylist, and i want to save them to a file, it saves the new data, but in the process, it duplicates the data that is already held in the text file.

I want the program to be able to overwrite the data in the text file and write the new data coming in. I tried deleting the text file if it existed but it doesn't work. It is shown in the code line. Is there any way I can get around this obstacle?

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can add a check if same name file exists than delete it and create new and store data in it. By doing that you will always have a fresh data without duplication.

Comment: @Ronnie7777: that's what he's doing already. And it's completely useless. Read my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because, although you're deleting the file if it already exists, the deletion probably fails: you should check the value returned by `delete()`. Re-creating the `File` object is also completely useless, BTW.

Thre reason it fails is probably because you never close the writer to the file, thus preventing it from being deleted. You should use the [try-with-resources construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure the writer is always closed when you're done with it.

Finally, there is no need to delete the file if it already exists. Just open a FileWriter with `false` as second argument, and it won't append to the end of the file, but overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. And besides we make mistakes

Answer (score 0):

By making the second argument "true," you're opening the file in append mode, which means it will tack on whatever you write to the end of the file. Try creating your FileWriter without append=true, or explicitly make append=false, and see what that does.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

```
if(action.equals("Save Person List"))
    {
        f1 = new File("PersonList.txt");
        if(f1.exists())
        {
            f1.delete();
            f1 = new File("PersonList.txt");
        }

        try {
            fWriter = new FileWriter(f1, false);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        pWriter = new PrintWriter(fWriter, true);

        for(Person p: pList)
        {
            pWriter.println(p.getFName());
            pWriter.println(p.getLName());
            pWriter.println(p.getPNo());
            pWriter.println(p.getSalary());
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Person List Stored in File 'PersonList.txt'");
    }
```